# Symbol of a linear partial differential operator with smooth coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $P = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_\alpha(x)D_x^\alpha$ act on $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ where $a_\alpha$ are smooth and $D_x^\alpha = (-i)^{|\alpha|}\partial_x^\alpha$. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_of_a_differential_operator), it states that the total symbol of $P$ is $p(x, \xi) = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_\alpha(x)\xi^\alpha$ and that this has the property: 
$$ Pu(x) = (2\pi)^{-n} \int e^{ix\xi} p(x, \xi) \hat{u}(\xi) d\xi. $$

I can see this in the case $a_\alpha(x) \equiv a_\alpha$ are constants, since $\widehat{D_x^\alpha u} = \xi^\alpha\hat{u}$, but if $a_\alpha$ is not a constant then taking Fourier transform introduces a convolution. Even if $P = a_\alpha(x) D_x^\alpha$, i.e. looking at one term,

$$ Pu(x) = (2\pi)^{-n} \int e^{ix\xi}\widehat{Pu}(\xi)d\xi = (2\pi)^{-n} \int e^{ix\xi} \int e^{-iy\xi}a_\alpha(y)D_y^\alpha u(y)dyd\xi, $$

so I can't see how the formula holds, i.e. how $a_\alpha(y)$ becomes $a_\alpha(x)$. So my question is: how does the first equation hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from $P = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_\alpha(x)D_x^\alpha$,

$$ Pu  = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_\alpha(x)\mathcal (F^{-1} \mathcal FD_x^\alpha u)(x) = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_\alpha(x)\mathcal \int e^{ix\xi} \underbrace{\widehat{D_x^\alpha u}(\xi)}_{=\xi^\alpha \hat u(\xi)} d\xi = \int e^{ix\xi} \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_\alpha(x) \xi^\alpha \hat u(\xi) d\xi $$
so the symbol is $p(x,\xi)=\sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_\alpha(x) \xi^\alpha$. The above equalities are reversible so you can also start with the symbol $p(x,\xi)$.

Comment: Thank you - it all makes sense now. Just out of curiosity, do you know why my approach is incorrect? As in why $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}(a_\alpha(x)D_x^\alpha u)$ doesn't seem to be as tractable as $a_\alpha(x)(\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}D_x^\alpha u)$?

Comment: @Riley no problem - I didn't make the definition, but my feeling is its precisely the issue you noted (appearance of convolutions) that the second is chosen as the definition of the symbol, rather than the first

Comment: thanks for your thoughts on this. I really appreciate your help!